# Sorting of 2 different datagrids

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

Is it possible to sync two different datagrids that contains similar values columns? (I can put it on a single datagrid, but I plan to do something else.)

That is, if I sort datagrid 1, datagrid 2 will also sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can add a ColumnSortHandler to one Datagrid. In this handler you can call event.getColumn() to see which column has been used for sorting, and event.isSortAscending() to get the direction of the sort. Then you can push the corresponding column to the sort list in the other Datagrid and call a sort event on it:

```
tableA.addColumnSortHandler(new ColumnSortEvent.Handler() {

    @Override
    public void onColumnSort(ColumnSortEvent event) {
        Column<MyObject, String> columnA = event.getColumn();
        // find columnB in tableB that corresponds to columnA in tableA
        tableB.getColumnSortList().push(new ColumnSortInfo(columnB, event.isSortAscending()));
        ColumnSortEvent.fire(tableB, tableB.getColumnSortList());
    }
});
```

Comment: Assuming I will add the ColumnSortHandle in datagridA and push it on datagGridB, is it possible to do it vice versa?

Comment: Of course. You can attach a handler to both of them.

Comment: thanks, although i am not successful in doing this task, you gave me a good place to start at. Can you edit the code you provided? its a little blurry to me (which is Datagrid A/Datagrid b, sorry im a newbie in gwt. Thanks)